# Null assertion error

Tags: c

```
for(i=1;i<dmax;i++){
    /*need to find length of / number of digits in integer
    before converting to string*/
    intlen = 1;
    /*prevents log10(0) equations*/
    if(factorstr[i].k){
        intlen += (int)floor(log10((float)factorstr[i].k));
    }
    /*so total length to be added to factors is
    intlen + 1 (from c in factor) + 1 (from \n) = 2 + intlen*/
    factorsize += 2 + intlen;
    if(factorsize>factors_size){
        factors_size += (factorsize + 1);
        printf("factors before realloc = %s, %d\n",factors,factors_size);
        factors = realloc(factors,factors_size);
        printf("factors after realloc = %s, %d\n",factors, factorsize);
        assert( factors != NULL );
    }

    sprintf(factors+last,"%c%d\n",factorstr[i].c,factorstr[i].k);
    last += intlen+2;
}
```

Hi,

This section of code is designed to concatenate a char and integer from a struct (that holds one `char` and one `int`, `c` and `k` respectively) followed by a `\n`. However, the line

`assert( factors != NULL );`

will cause the program to crash roughly 1/5 of the time I run it (after running it repeatedly).

The two `printf` functions below and above the assert are to help me have a better idea of what's going on, and during crashes it looks like

`factors before realloc = [massive string], 100
factors after realloc = (null), 51`

Where the bottom number, `factorsize` is an `int` that keeps track of how much memory being used based on amount of integers, characters and nullbytes in the string, which is then added to an int `factors_size` which keeps track of how much memory `factors` has alloced to it.

When the former exceeds the latter, I realloc `factor_size + factors + 1` amount of bytes to it before adding the string.

However, when I removed `last += intlen+2` (the second last line) I get no assertion errors at all.

Why is this happening? I need that last line to properly concatenate the integer + char + nullbyte to the string rather than overriding it, so removing it isn't really an option

that is, if I have a0\n which fills `factors[0], [1], [2]`, the next sprintf will go to `factors + last` = `factors[3]`, if for example it were ',0\n', `factors [3], [4], [5]` would become `',0\n'`, resulting in factors = `"a0\n,0\n"` and so on

Comment: Don't use `assert` to check for success/failure. First of all it's only enabled in debug builds, secondly it will abruptly abort the program if the assert failed, which is really bad in any kind of production software.

Comment: Also, don't reassign to the pointer you `realloc`, think about what happens when `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, you will then loose the original pointer so you can't `free` it later, leading to a possible memory leak.

Comment: Finally, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: I'm following my assignment's instructions - I have to follow every `malloc/realloc` with an assert, and multiple examples given to us use the `ptr = realloc(ptr,reallocsize)` template, so I'm fairly confused - why is that bad?

Comment: Like I said, if `realloc` returns `NULL`, then you loose the original pointer you passed to `realloc`, and in production/release/*real* code where you can't use `assert` that might lead to a *memory-leak*.

Comment: Then what would be a better way to reallocate memory?

Comment: Oh `realloc` works just fine, but assign it to a temporary pointer and then if it's not `NULL` *then* assign it to the original pointer. Although if you are *instructed* to use `assert` it really doesn't matter. Just remember it for the future when you stop using `assert` for checks like that.

Comment: Do I just declare a temporary point like `char *tmp;` and do `tmp = realloc(...)` and `if (tmp){ factors = tmp`? The only difference is now, I'm crashing 1/5 the time without any error message